# Need help with an integral involving the Dirac delta function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

I'm having trouble evaluating this integral, which involves the Dirac delta function:

$$
  \int\limits_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi x)}{x}  \delta \left[ (x^2-1)(x-2) \right]  \mathrm{d}x
$$

I think I should use the following relation:

$$\int_a^b f(t) \delta(x-c)\,\mathrm dx=\begin{cases}f(c)&\text{if }a<c<b,\\0&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$

But I don't know how to apply it to this particular problem. Is there any other property of this function I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the property

$$\delta(g(x)) = \sum_i \frac{\delta(x-c_i)}{\vert g'(c_i) \vert},\tag{1}$$

where $c_i$ are the roots of $g$. This may look strange but the [proof is not very difficult](http://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Delta%20Functions/Simplified%20Dirac%20Delta.pdf).

Also, the relation that you wrote is not correct. Once you expressed the delta as shown in (1), then you use:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\delta(x-x_0) dx = \begin{cases}
f(x_0) & \text{if } a<x_0<b,\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Your zeros are clearly $-1, 1, 2$.